# remove lines that are odd from textfile android

Tags: android, line, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a `textfile` and wanted to do some filtering. For that I used a `BufferedReader` to read the file and created a `String` called `"line"` to read all lines. I would like to check if a `line` starts with a specific `string` (in my case "#") and the `line` after it (the next line) doesn't start with another specific `String` (in my case "h"). And if the "the next line" starts with "h" the line should be removed.

So basically I want to make every line even.

Example:

This is a text file:

```
#line
ham
#line2
house
#line3
#line4
heart
#line5
hand
```

(for this example line4 should be removed)

I tried something like this:

```
if (line.startsWith("#") && nextline != "h"){
                        // remove this line
                        // There is no definition for "nextline"
                    }
```

for reading lines:

```
try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                String line;

                position2string = String.valueOf(wrongpos + 1 + ".");

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith("h")) {
                        lineStore.add(line);

                    }



                    if (line.startsWith("#")) {
                        line2 = line.replace("#EXTINF:-1,", "");
                        line3 = +richtigeposition + 1 + ". " + line2;
                        richtigeposition++;
                        namelist.add(line3);


                        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                this,
                                R.layout.listitem, R.id.firsttext,
                                namelist);

                        mainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                }
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainAcvtivity", + e.toString());
            }
```

Edit (Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen, I found a solution, but I'm getting  NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()  this Exception at  `bw.write(last);`  , sorry I'm quite new to programming) :

My current code:

```
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));


            String line;

            position2string = String.valueOf(wrongpos + 1 + ".");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


                if (last != null && (!line.startsWith("h") || !lastPound)) {
                    bw.write(last);
                }
                lastPound = line.startsWith("#");
                last = curr;




                if (line.startsWith("h")) {
                    lineStore.add(line);

                }



                if (line.startsWith("#")) {
                    line2 = line.replace("#EXTINF:-1,", "");
                    line3 = +richtigeposition + 1 + ". " + line2;
                    richtigeposition++;
                    namelist.add(line3);


                    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this,
                            R.layout.listitem, R.id.firsttext,
                            namelist);

                    mainlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }

            }
            br.close();
      //Exeption is here ==>    bw.write(last);
            bw.close();







        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in another way that probably will save your time and some code lines. You could get all file lines into a list and then it would be much easier to interact with it:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(*path_to_file*), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

After storing your file lines into List you become able to iterate thro it to search for needed lines. To avoid `NullPointerException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` don't forget to specify right bounds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (lines.get(i).startsWith("#") && !lines.get(i + 1).startsWith("h")) {
        lines.remove(i+1);
    }
}
```

After that, you're able to store your List into a file:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(*path_to_file*), lines);
```

I tested that and output looked like that:

[image]

--- Update ---

To perform IO operations you could use `Scanner` and `FileWriter`:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("in.txt"));

while (s.hasNext()) {
    lines.add(s.next());
}

s.close();
```

And for output:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("out.txt");

for (String str : lines) {
    writer.write(str + System.lineSeparator());
}

writer.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only works with minimum API 26 . My minimum API is API 21

Comment: @Creesch2.0 as an alternative you could change `Files` methods to `Scanner` for example. If you're interested I'm able to modify answer.

Comment: Yes please, I'm new and I'm stuck in this problem.

Comment: @Creesch2.0 these classes are available from API 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using a standard `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`.  We can iterate the file, keeping track of whether the previous line started with a `#`, as well as keeping track of the content of the previous line.  For each line read, if the previous line did *not* start with `#` *or* the current line did not start with `h`, then the previous line gets written.  Otherwise, the previous line is omitted, effectively removing it from the new output file.

```
boolean lastPound = false;
String last;
String curr;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("in.txt");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (last != null && (!line.startsWith("h") || !lastPound)) {
                lines.add(last);
            }
            lastPound = line.startsWith("#");
            last = curr;
        }
        lines.add(last);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
```

Note that we also add the final line to the list after the `while` loop.  The final line of the file always gets written, because it isn't followed by another line (and therefore cannot be followed by a line which starts with `h`).

Comment: I just wanted to add the filtered lines into an arraylist

Comment: Then replace the calls to `bw.write` with code to add that previous line to an arraylist.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do that

Comment: I'm getting a NullPointerException after the while loop at bw.write(last);

Comment: Refer to my earlier comment.

Comment: But I don't know how to add the previous line to an arraylist that's why I'm here

Comment: @Creesch2.0 I have edited my answer to store the line in an arraylist instead of writing them to file.